# How to Read POST Arguments in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, post, bokeh, tornado

I'm working on an application built on bokeh. I'd like it to process both GET and POST requests. In order to read the GET requests I simply use `request_args = curdoc().session_context.request.arguments` which reads them in as a convenient dictionary. However, when I try to submit a POST request, this is all I get: `<html><title>405: Method Not Allowed</title><body>405: Method Not Allowed</body></html>`

It looks like the underlying Tornado layer needs to be modified (perhaps by subclassing the RequestHandler). However, I'm not sure how to get bokeh to do that, since so far I've only accessed the bokeh layer and haven't touched Tornado at all. The bokeh documentation refers to POST requests in some places so I'd expect it to be a simple configuration adjustment but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Unfortunately this would not be a trivial task at all. No one has ever asked about POST requests, so only GET requests are currently supported. You would need to re-implement a substantial chunk of the Bokeh server just to insert those extra handlers. You might consider making a [github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to request supporting POST as a potential new feature.

Comment: Interesting. The documentation on [XSRF Cookies](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#xsrf-cookies) mentions POST, so I assumed it was implemented somewhere.

Comment: So you haven't actually explained at all what or where you want POSTs handled? Are you trying to make custom endpoints? Or are you talking about the existing GET endpoints for creating app sessions? You need to explain, in *much more detail*, what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: All I'm looking for is for the arguments in a POST request to be accessible in the application layer. Some of the arguments contain potentially sensitive data, which is why I'd like to use POST instead of GET, but I'm just looking for the same functionality that's currently in place for `curdoc().session_context.request.arguments`.